# run function recursively over table

Tags: iterator, simulation, kdb

Every call to function `fx` left-joins a new column to `x` based on some data in table `t` and integers `p` and `q`. 
I show desired iteration over values of `p` and `q` below but do not know how to do it properly using KDB+ iterators.
**Sample data and solution:**

```
x:([]date:(2013.07.01+til 10);ords:til 10); /Some random table with date (key column)
t:p:([]date:(2013.07.01+1000#til 200);px:1000?10e); /Some random table.
fx:{[x;t;p;q]
    /Do something with t;p;q and left-join output column to x on date;
    t:([]date:(2013.07.01+til 10);ords:10?10000);
    col_names:(`date;`$""sv(string(`P);string(p);string(`Q);string(q)));
    t: x lj 1!col_names xcol t;
    :t
    };

/Run simulation for p=1 to 2 and q=3 to 4 as follows:
fx[ fx[ fx[ fx[x;t;1;3]; t;2;3]; t;1;4]; t;2;4] /How to do this iteration properly?
```

Last statement has two for loops on `p` and `q` from 1to2 and 3to4 respectively. I am sure there is a better way to achieve this using scan/over but I am not able to figure it out. Could someone help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pass `t` as a projection as it remains constant over each iteration and then use scan iterate over the other variables

```
fx[;t;;]/[x;1 2 1 2;3 3 4 4]
```

Comment: Thanks @MarkKelly. However, `... ;1 2 1 2; 3 3 4 4]` in `fx[;t]/[x;1 2 1 2;3 3 4 4]` is still manually writing the permutations. Is it somehow possible to replace it with something like `(1+til 2) cross (3+til 2)` into this expression to make it more generic?

Comment: You can use the dot operator `.` to apply both lists as separate arguments `fx[;t]/[x] . flip (1+til 2) cross (3+til 2)` or you could set the permutations to a variable and pass in the first and last e.g `l:flip (1+til 2) cross (3+til 2); fx[;t]/[x;l 0;l 1]`